# Azure search: how to create a search index of complex type for blobs

Tags: azure, api, azure-cognitive-search

I have a blob storage that has a number of folders, each folder has a number of pdf documents. I now want to create an azure search index which indexes the data by folder level, but includes a complex type structure (Collection(edm.ComplexType) that allows me to include all the documents. So the index looks like this:

```
{"name": "index",
"fields":
[
    {"name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": true, "key": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
    {"name": "folderName", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true, "analyzer": "en.microsoft"},
    {"name": "documents", "type": "Collection(Edm.ComplexType)",
    "fields": [
        {"name": "documentName", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true, "analyzer": "en.microsoft"},
        {"name": "content", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false, "analyzer": "en.microsoft", "synonymMaps": ["synonymsmap"]},
        {"name": "documentType", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true, "analyzer": "en.microsoft"},
        {"name": "language", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true, "analyzer": "en.microsoft"}
    ]
    }
]
```

}

Does anyone know how I should approach this? I have been creating and populating indexes using rest api.

I am thinking maybe I need to create a folder-level index structure and populate the folder-level details from some sql-table before populating the sub-fields with the blobs through skillset and indexer etc?

**EDITS:**
Maybe my ideas above are completely off-track. What I want to do is to search a term and return folder names based on the aggregate relevancy of documents within folders. Not sure if this is achievable in search or have to be processed afterwards. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

*Does anyone know how I should approach this? I have been creating and populating indexes using rest api.*

**A:** If you want this structure, then you're right. You'll need to create your index and push data by yourself (rest api is one of the options)

*I am thinking maybe I need to create a folder-level index structure and populate the folder-level details from some sql-table before populating the sub-fields with the blobs through skillset and indexer etc?*

**A:** This is not a good idea, when searching using a particular term, you'll need to query all the possible indexes and do the ordering by yourself.

I personally would create a simple structure, which no complex types:

```
{
    "name": "index",
    "fields":
    [
        {"name": "id", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": true, "key": true, "searchable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": false},
        {"name": "folderName", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true, "analyzer": "en.microsoft"},
        {"name": "documentName", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true, "analyzer": "en.microsoft"},
        {"name": "content", "type": "Edm.String", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false, "analyzer": "en.microsoft", "synonymMaps": ["synonymsmap"]},
        {"name": "documentType", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true, "analyzer": "en.microsoft"},
        {"name": "language", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "searchable": true, "retrievable": true, "filterable": true, "sortable": false, "facetable": true, "analyzer": "en.microsoft"}
    ]
}
```

want to retrieve all documents by a particular folder?

```
search=*&$filter=folderName eq 'abc'
```

want to retrieve a particular documents in a particular folder?

```
search=*&$filter=folderName eq 'abc' and documentName eq 'x.docx'
```

want to all documents that contain a particular term?

```
search=mickey mouse&$orderBy=folderName
```

simple and effective

Comment: Thanks very much. Ultimately I am trying to create an interface that allows me to search a particular term and returns most relevant folder names (based on frequency of the term being mentioned across all documents within each folder). That's the reason I wanted to index it on folder-level.

Comment: the way I've recommended will provide you that. TFxIDF is the default for calculating relevancy, no need a complex type for that.

Comment: I assume TFxIDF will calculate relevancy on document level but not folderName level? I want something like, if folder A has 90% documents mentioning 'mickey mouse' and folder B has 20%, then I want to return folder A before folder B. Does this match with what ur understanding was?

Comment: you can mark folder name as facetable and use it as part of the query

Comment: the folder name is already set as facetable. could u pls kindly provide an example query?

Comment: Actually, I think you'll need to use a scoring profile for that. I would need to do a few tests but I can't at this moment. I think it's enough for you to get started.